# How to Design a UI in razor view / MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I'm very very very brand new to MVC. I have a basic knowledge of ASP.NET. I'm just started learning MVC. I am having a tough time designing a UI. So please help me to design a page in MVC4. I'm used to drag-and-drop based UI building components but not this HTML based designing a page.

Can you please help me to design a page in Razor View?

Comment: I highly recommend to go through this website http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials you may add the components using html helpers or simply use asp as view engine then you get the toolbar to drag and drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you find it difficult because you are focusing on the wrong thing. You don't design a page in Razor, you design a page in html/css, the classical way, THEN you add some razor code for data.

For example, copy _Layout.cshtml to Layout.html, modify it to your heart content. Put the CSS and JS scripts back as you would normally do in HTML, use your favorite tool. Once you are done, copy and paste back the razor stuff for JS and CSS, et voila !

If you don't already have a tool for HTML design, you may want to download Microsoft Expression 4 free version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179

Hope this helps,
Bernard